# How to minimize a space between a chapter title and a top page

Tags: spacing, chapters, fncychap

I would minimize a space between a chapter title and a top of page.
there is what i have(black line) and what i will do(red line).

[image]

A red line is a space wich i would to use instead of the space in the black line.

this is a code.

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage[Lenny]{fncychap}
\begin{document}
\chapter{Fancy title with Latex}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Please state explicitly what you mean by "minimize a space between a chapter title and a top of page". Do you want to elminate the space entirely, or do you want to reduce it by ca 50% (as appears to be suggested by the red line in your sketch)?

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your sketch correctly, you'd like to reduce the distance between the upper edge of the text block and the chapter header by half. If this understanding is correct, you may achieve your goal by adding the following code to the preamble:

```
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\makeatletter
\patchcmd{\@makechapterhead}{\vspace*{50\p@}}{\vspace*{25\p@}}{}{}
\makeatother
```

A compilable example, which assumes that the vertical space between the upper edge of the text block and *unnumbered* chapters should be reduced by 50% as well:

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage[Lenny]{fncychap}

\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage{showframe} % omit this package in real document
\makeatletter
\patchcmd{\@makechapterhead}{\vspace*{50\p@}}{\vspace*{25\p@}}{}{}
\patchcmd{\@makeschapterhead}{\vspace*{50\p@}}{\vspace*{25\p@}}{}{}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\chapter{Fancy title with Latex}
\chapter*{An unnumbered chapter}
\end{document}
```

Here's the resulting screenshot (the framelines are drawn by the `showframe` package; don't load this package in a real document.)

[image]

For comparison, the next screenshot shows what the title page would look like without the `\patchcmd` instructions. As you can see, the distance between the top frame line (which represents the upper edge of the text block) and the upper decorative line of the chapter header is twice as large (50pt vs 25pt) as it is in the first screenshot.

[image]

Comment: it produces a same result, i can't reduce a space between a chapter and margin top of page

Comment: @YounessGI - The space between the upper edge of the text block (which isn't the same as the upper edge of the pge!) is *definitely* reduced -- by half -- in the example code I provided. If the code suggested above isn't working for you, it must because you have different code. Please advise as to how your document code differs from what I posted above.

Comment: I want to raise the chapter title display of the first page of the chapter at the top, because it is displayed at the bottom.

Comment: @YounessGI -- If your chapter headers really are at the *bottom* of the page, then there's something very odd going on. If you want no space between the upper edge of the text block (which is not the same as the upper edge of the page), you should change `\vspace*{25\p@}` to `\vspace*{0\p@}`.  (I realize now I hadn't understood your sketch correctly.)

Comment: that's not what I want, I want the chapter display to be a little higher than it is now, i find to reduce margin top of chapter page

Comment: @YounessGI - I'm afraid I simply don't understand what you want. Very sorry. Naturally, since my proposed solution is evidently worthless to you, I will delete it in a few minutes.

Comment: I want to raise the display of the title of the chapter as it is mentioned in the figure attached in red line to reduce the space between the title and the header of the page

Comment: @YounessGI - The answer I posted above does *exactly* what you now say you want to achieve. Specifically, the vertical distance between the upper edge of the text block and the top of the chapter header is reduced from 50pt to 25pt. (You're obviously free to choose a value other than 25pt.) However, you've also indicated that this solution just isn't working for you. I asked you to indicate in which ways your document deviates from mine, but you haven't addressed this matter. I'm really sorry, but I can't seem to find a way to help you.

Comment: I am tested the code, nothing is changed, please can you tested a solution on ur machine !!

Comment: @YounessGI - I've added two screenshots to demonstrate that my code works. If it's not working for you, it must be because you have a different document setup. E.g., do you maybe have a document class other than `report`?